# How to test jersey2 request filters?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jersey-2.0

In my jersey-2 application I'm using a very simple `ContainerRequestFilter` that will check for basic authentication (probably reinventing the wheel, but bear with me). Filter goes somewhat like this

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
    String authHeader = context.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(authHeader)) {
        log.info("Auth header is missing.");
        context.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .entity(ErrorResponse.authenticationRequired())
                .build());
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to write a test for it, mocking the `ContainerRequestContext` object.

```
@Test
public void emptyHeader() throws Exception {

    when(context.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)).thenReturn(null);

    filter.filter(context);

    Response r = Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .entity(ErrorResponse.authenticationRequired())
            .build();

    verify(context).abortWith(eq(r));

}
```

This test fails on the `eq(r)` call, even if looking at the string representation of the `Response` objects they are the same. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since I had the same question, I did it like this:

```
@Test
public void abort() {

    new MyFilter().filter(requestContext);

    ArgumentCaptor<Response> responseCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Response.class);
    verify(requestContext).abortWith(responseCaptor.capture());

    Response response = responseCaptor.getValue();
    assertNotNull(response);
    JerseyResponseAssert.assertThat(response)
            .hasStatusCode(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need the eq() method. You should verify that context. abortWith(r) was called. I might be missing something though because you've not included what eq(r) is.

Comment: `eq()` comes from Mockito. Sure I could do without it, something like `verify(context).abortWith(any())`, but then the test would pass for all errors instead of just `UNAUTHORIZED`. Not what I want/what I'm testing.

Comment: My point was that you should directly put the object into the method right? That method doesn't take a Matcher as far as I can tell.